# The fields does not show the values when error in Php validation

Tags: php

I have these coding below for registration form. But it resets the filled out fields as empty and shows the error field. I have to fill the form again from first. How can i resolve this problem. Thanks in advance for read this and helping me to resolve

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$domain=$_POST['domain'];
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$sname=$_POST['sname'];
$tel=$_POST['tel'];
if($domain==""){
    $error="<h4>Enter Domain </h4>";    
}elseif($fname == ""){
    $error="<h4>Enter Firstname </h4>"; 
}elseif($sname == "")
{
    $error="<h4 >Enter Surname</h4>";   
}elseif($tel=="")
{
    $error="<h4 >Enter telephono no</h4>";  
}
else {

$sql11=mysql_query("INSERT INTO domain VALUES('','$domain','$fname','$sname','$tel')");
echo $sql;
$db->query($sql);

    }
```

Comment: How to even start helping here? ...

Comment: put `echo $_POST['field name'];` in the value region of the field

Comment: There is no magical "repopulate_form()" function. You have to do that manually by setting `value` on each input field.

Comment: If you use different `if` statements instead of `else-if` ones you will get all errors at once. Otherwise you will get a different error on each consecutive request.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: domain in D:\xampp\htdocs\deena\domainreg.php on line 82. When i'm trying echo $_post['fieldname'], this shows error like this

Comment: can you put your form sample here?

Comment: check the action, method, submit button, input field names

Comment: Last **}** is missing. Try checking true conditions instead of empty states.

Comment: also have a look at empty() and isset() functions in the php.net documentation. It's much better than using if($variable=="") ... right now if someone input whitespaces in the field for example then the variable will not be == "" (it would be "  ") So the person wouldn't get the error, also If you plan to do registration forms try to google some form validation tutorials, you will improve your forms a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="domain" id="domain" value="<?php echo isset($domain) ? $domain : ''; ?>" />
```

This will work.